# angular js ng-keyup not working for password strength check

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i m new to angular programming.

so i was given a task to create an app in angular to check the strength of password based on input string length.

the following is my code , please check it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>password strength</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    .red{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .orange{
        background-color: orange;
    }
    .green{
        background-color: green;
    }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ans= angular.module("myapp",[]);
        ans.controller("pswdstr",function($scope){
            $scope.show=function(){
                var pswdlen= $scope.pswd.length;
                if (pswdlen==0) 
                {
                    $scope.color="";
                    $scope.validation="Enter password";
                }
                else if (pswdlen<=5) 
                {
                    $scope.color="red";
                    $scope.validation="password is weak";
                }
                else if (pswdlen>5 && pswdlen<=8) 
                {
                    $scope.color="orange";
                    $scope.validation="password is ok";
                }
                else if (pswdlen>8) 
                {
                    $scope.color="green";
                    $scope.validation="password is strong";
                };

            };

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="pswdstr">
<label for="pswd">Enter password</label>
<input type="password" name="pswd" id="pswd" ng-model="pswd" ng-keypress="show()"></input>
<div class='{{ color }}' ng-if="pswd">
{{ validation }}
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the problem i am facing is that the app is not working. 
when the string length is below 5 or below 8 according to the condition the div color should change to red along with its validation. but its not working that way.. please help.

and guys please post the detailed answer as i am a beginner in this scripting.
thank you.

Comment: may be help u http://jsfiddle.net/jaredwilli/5RrX7/

Comment: too hard to understand.. in console when i invoke ng-keyup, in console its show $scope.pswd is not defined!! pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your problem be define nd-model as ng-model.
i put your sample here and work corrctly.

use ng-change insted of ng-keypress. now it work correctly.

```js
var ans= angular.module("myapp",[]);
        ans.controller("pswdstr",function($scope){
            $scope.show=function(){
                var pswdlen= $scope.pswd.length;
                if (pswdlen==0) 
                {
                    $scope.color="";
                    $scope.validation="Enter password";
                }
                else if (pswdlen<=5) 
                {
                    $scope.color="red";
                    $scope.validation="password is weak";
                }
                else if (pswdlen>5 && pswdlen<=8) 
                {
                    $scope.color="orange";
                    $scope.validation="password is ok";
                }
                else if (pswdlen>8) 
                {
                    $scope.color="green";
                    $scope.validation="password is strong";
                };

            };

        });
```

```css
.red{
        background-color: red;
    }
    .orange{
        background-color: orange;
    }
    .green{
        background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="pswdstr">
<label for="pswd">Enter password</label>
<input type="password" name="pswd" id="pswd" ng-model="pswd" ng-change="show()">
<div class='{{ color }}' ng-if="pswd">
{{ validation }}
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-change` instead of `ng-keypress` inside `input`

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/uudt6h04/4/) working code

Answer (score 0):

use keydown instread of keypress and instread of

```
 $scope.pswd.length
```

use

```
 $scope.pswd.length+1
```

and alert in your check to see its working or not